# Most accurate values found for Riemann nontrivial zeroes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I am attempting to find the ratio between two non trivial zeroes for the Riemann Zeta function. However, plugging it into Wolfram Alpha I get funky results which I suspect to be a product of inaccuracy. Where can I find the most accurate possible values for Riemann Zeta nontrivial zeroes?

Comment: Can you please share the "funky results"? I'm just curious.

Comment: Highly doubt Wolfram has inaccurate values (e.g. [this seems fine](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=zetazero%281%29)).... It would be more productive to share the results and describe what's wrong with them. That, said, [here](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/constants/zeta100.html).

Comment: One place is here: https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~odlyzko/zeta_tables/index.html

Comment: @Sahaj I kept on getting seemingly random complex numbers, when I was expecting a value close to one for the ratio, since both nontrivial zeroes approach, obviously, zero. However, it turns out that the "funky" results actually had an absolute value of one, just as I suspected.

Answer (score 2):

The [LMFDB has zeta zeros](https://www.lmfdb.org/zeros/zeta/) to approximately 30 digits of accuracy. Rather, it has the first 103,800,788,359 zeros. This relies on the work of Platt, [10.1090/S0025-5718-2014-02884-6](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-2014-02884-6), who computed these and more to extreme accuracy.